# Parse error with JSONObject in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-8.1

I have a JSON file saved locally that is being opened and read from successfully, but every time I try to parse it it fails. I've checked the JSON online but I can't find fault with it.

```
{
    "Groups": [
         {
            "UniqueId": "233619708",
            "Title": "Partno",
            "Customer": "Customer",
            "Items": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using a modified version of the JSON reader included in a sample source in VS, which looks like this:

```
private async Task GetSampleDataAsync()
{
    if (this._groups.Count != 0)
        return;

    StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("DB.json");
    string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    if (jsonText == "") {
        await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("File Blank!").ShowAsync(); 
        }
    JsonObject jsonObject;
    if(JsonObject.TryParse(jsonText, out jsonObject))
    { await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("File Read Error! Json Couldn't Parse!").ShowAsync();
    throw new FormatException(jsonText);
    }
    if(jsonObject.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
    {
        JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
        Part group = new Part(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                    groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                    groupObject["Customer"].GetString(),

                                                    groupObject["Description"].GetString());

        foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
        {
            JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
            group.Items.Add(new Box(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),

                                               Convert.ToInt16( itemObject["Qty"].GetNumber()),
                                               itemObject["Location"].GetString(),
                                               group.UniqueId));

        }
        this.Groups.Add(group);
    }
}
```

Any ideas anyone? Every time `JsonObject.TryParse` runs it returns false, and `JsonObject.Parse` returns a `KeyMissingException`.
Thanks.
(btw, I know there's nothing in the items part, I've tried both with and without...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the other Json conversion method?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText);
```

I remember from having to grab data from bitcoin API's that when one method didn't work as expected it was worth trying the other one.
I think it had something to do with JObject.Parse being for JSON Objects and JsonConvert.Deserialize being for JSON arrays.

EDIT:

This will parse and deserialize the JSON you provided.

```
    public class MyJsonObject
    {
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<JsonObjectItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonObjectItem
    {
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }
        public string Qty { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }

public void ParseJson(string jsonText)
{
    JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

    if(jsonObject != null)
    {
        JToken token = null;
        if(jsonObject.TryGetValue("Groups", out token))
        {
            foreach (var partData in token.Children())
            {
                if (!partData.HasValues)
                    continue;

                MyJsonObject obj = partData.ToObject<MyJsonObject>();

                Part group = new Part(obj.UniqueId, obj.Title, obj.Customer, obj.Description);

                if(obj.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in obj.Items)
                    {

                        short qty;
                        if(!Int16.TryParse(item.Qty, out qty))
                        {
                            // Decide what to do if is error with parsing qty.
                        }

                        group.Items.Add(new Box(item.UniqueId, qty, item.Location, obj.UniqueId));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

HOWEVER - Depending upon the exact make up of your 'Part' class, you may even be able to simplify this even further and change:

```
MyJsonObject obj = partData.ToObject<MyJsonObject>();
```

to:

```
Part group = partData.ToObject<Part>();
```

and that should populate the properties and list of items in one go.

Hope that is helpful

Comment: When i use that i just get a "Cannot parse" error, saying my list has to be a list....

Comment: His loOKs promising ill give it a go and get back to you